# Can I replace in MySQL all values in the column by their positions in the ordered list of values

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have the following table:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| 1    | 1.1  | 9.3  |
| 2    | 7.9  | 1.3  |
| 3    | 3.7  | 7.3  |
| 4    | 9.0  | 5.7  |
```

I need to order the rows using the weighted sum of the `col2` and `col3`. It can be easily done in the following way:

```
select * from mytable order by (0.8*col2 + 0.2*col3)
```

Now I want to do almost the same, the only difference is that I need to replace the actual values in the `col2` and `col3` by there position in the ordered list of all values in the column. For example, in the second column the following replacements should be done:

```
(1.1 -> 1, 3.7 -> 2, 7.9 -> 3, 9.0 -> 4)
```

Does anybody know if there is an easy way to construct a query that would do that. In other words, I would like to have something like that:

```
select * from mytable order by (0.8*modified(col2) + 0.2*modified(col3))
```

where the `modified` function replace the value by its position in the ordered list of all the values from the column.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SET @cnt := 0;
update mytable m ,
(
SELECT
    @cnt := @cnt + 1 as newid,
    col1
 from mytable order by (0.8*col2 + 0.2*col3)
) as mysorted
set a.col2 = mysorted.newid
where a.col1 = mysorted.col1
```